# Question with ParametricNDSolveValue

Tags: numerical-integration, numerics

When solving the following system:

```
g[a_,b_] := c /. FindRoot[a + b == c, {c, 0}]

pf = 
  ParametricNDSolveValue[{y''[x] == g[a,b] y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], 
    y[0] == a, y'[0] == 1}, Integrate[y[s]^2, {s, 0., b}], {x, 0, b}, {a, b}];
```

*Mathematica* gives me two error messages, which say:

> FindRoot::nlnum: The function value {0. +a+b}is not a list of numbers with dimensions {1} at {c} = {0.}. >>
>
> ReplaceAll::reps: {FindRoot[a+b==c,{c,0}]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. >>

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to preempt symbolic evaluation:

```
g[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ] := c /. FindRoot[a + b == c, {c, 0}]

pf = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y''[x] == g[a, b] y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], 
   y[0] == a, y'[0] == 1}, 
  Integrate[y[s]^2, {s, 0., b}], {x, 0, b}, {a, b}]
```

Comment: it works, thanks a lot. But I do not understand why `g[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ]` works

Comment: @user8583, when the command evaluates, before it gets to `ParametricNDSolve` it evaluates `g[a,b]` which you do not want. Try your `ParametricNDSolveValue[...]//Trace` to see what happens.

Comment: I get it. thanks